# Android Studio, utilizando productFlavors com Sufix eBuildVariant - ERRO nas classes dependentes

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle

tive que separar meu aplicativo em dois produtos, utilizando o productFlavors
no Gradle, funciona de boa, quando escolho a Build Variant pra compilar, ele realmente deixa de subir umas dependências dependendo da variant, porém nos códigos fonte ele já critica a falta da dependência, nem deixando eu compilar o app, vou passar abaixo os trechos...

```
 flavorDimensions 'versoes'
productFlavors {
    pagseguroVersao {
        dimension 'versoes'
        applicationIdSuffix '.pagseguro'
    }
    stoneVersao {
        dimension 'versoes'
        applicationIdSuffix '.stone'
    }
}
```

Daí dependendo da build variant eu baixo as dependências, dessa forma:

```
pagseguroVersaoImplementation 'br.com.uol.pagseguro.plugpagservice.wrapper:wrapper:1.7.6'

stoneVersaoImplementation "br.com.stone:stone-sdk:$stone_sdk_version"
stoneVersaoImplementation "br.com.stone:stone-sdk-posandroid:$stone_sdk_version"
```

reparem que nao utiilizo mais somente Implementation, agora vem prefixado a variant nesses casos, stoneVersao e pagseguroVersao

aí é que acontece , qndo rodo ele com a variant **Stone**, ele perde as referencias da dependência da Pagseguro e com isso, os código que dependem dela, começam a "da pau", e assim vice-versa, qndo escolho a **variat Pagseguro**, da pau nos código que utilizam **Stone**

Já dei boas pesquisadas mas nãp consigo encontrar a solução, to perdido!!

alguém pode ajudar?

obg!!

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que para o seu problema você precisa usar o dynamic features e não somente configurar o build variants.

[Nesse artigo](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-dynamic-feature-um-guia-pr%C3%A1tico-andr%C3%A9-ramos/) eu explico um pouco sobre como fiz isso para um módulo de um aplicativo que trabalhei.

TL;DR

Você precisará:

1. Criar um [wrapper](http://public.africa.cmu.edu/cbishop/jsmart/notes/Wrappers.html) que implemente uma interface em comum para os módulos (nesse caso stone e pagseguro);
2. Configurar os módulos do dynamic feature e instalar as dependências corretamente dentro de cada módulo;
3. Gerênciar a instalação dos módulos;
4. Carregar o código dos módulos (que implementa a interface do item 1) em tempo de execução.

Comment: Massa André, vou da uma olhada!! obg